# How to create custom classpath in Tomcat 9?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, classpath, classloader

We are planning to migrate tomcat server(current version we are using is 7) to version 9, Currently we are using VirtualWebAppLoader class to create custom class path, i.e., loading jars from external folder. But in Tomcat 9 this loader class is no longer available. How can I achieve this in tomcat 9?

Comment: Is your question answered? If so, please mark it answered.

Answer (score 7):

You can do so by adding a `Resources` element in your context descriptor:

This is descripted in [Apache Tomcat resources configuration documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/resources.html#Common_Attributes).

```
<Resources>
  <PreResources base="/definitly/existing/path/to/your/external/lib"
            className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet" readOnly="true"
            internalPath="/" webAppMount="/WEB-INF/lib" />
</Resources>
```

This adds a folder that may contain .jar files searched by Tomcat before the main resources. The type of child element decides about the order Tomcat searches for resources. The search order is:

- PreResources
- MainResources
- ClassResources
- JarResources
- PostResources